# CM10.1 SDK Level?

Tags: android, cyanogenmod

My app checks for the user's SDK level, for example, like this:

`if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18){ ... }`

I've had reports of users running CM10.1 that this returns `true`(and consequently crashes my app), even though I had the impression that CM10.1 is based on 4.2.2, rather than 4.3 (which would be CM10.2)? Has anyone else encountered this?

Thanks!

Comment: CM 10.1 is based on 4.2.2 maybe you should open a bug ?

Comment: Thanks, Imedinas. I'll test this further, there were only 2 crashes with this error in my Google Play Console yet (and both had a user message saying "I'm using CM10.1"), but then again I don't know how many of my users are on 10.1 in total :)...